# 80s/90s anime female fighters with different colored earrings and powers

Tags: story-identification, anime

I remember the girls going to an all-girl school together. When it's time to fight they "ask" something/-one for permission(?) to activate their power.

Each color (blue, black, red, green) is different with different powers. Each girl gets an earring to "seal" the pact with whoever to use the power.

The black power is "evil" and I remember the girl getting it by bonding(?) with some young boy who is a typical a**hole.

I can't remember what or who they were fighting, but they were fighting something.

Their eyes say something like "blu rose lvl restriction lifted".

Comment: It's 2005 instead of 80s/90s, but the heroes of [My-Otome](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Anime/MyOtome) draw their power from magical earrings.

Comment: If that's the correct answer, Nina may be the character with the black earring. And TVTropes also notes that "the Otomes' powers can only be activated by the vocal command of their 'masters'.", which fits what you said about asking permission. They all go to the same special school, but I can't tell if it's all-girl.

Comment: Actually, the girl with the black earring could be Tomoe, IF the young boy is actually a girl who isn't a "typical a**hole".

Comment: OP, does this video look familiar: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hi5HGQssGu0 - especially 0:46 in, where text appears on the earring, and it's possible to mistake it for the girl's eye.

Oh, and the correct anglicised spelling may be "Mai-Otome", not "My-Otome" - TVTropes and most Youtube uploads differ on this.

Comment: And at 4:17 in the video, one of the gems displays the text "ROBE: BLUE SKY SAPPHIRE". This text then vanishes and is replaced with "END RESTRICTION 1". This fits with the original, pre-edit version of the post where you mentioned seeing text similar to "blu rose lvl restriction lifted"

Comment: @Astrid_Redfern as with My-HiME before it, the My/Mai in the title is a play on words that only works in Japanese but the [https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/images/releases/products/109641.7ab6ec22869339abf298e40a7a3210ee.jpg](official) English title uses “My”. My-HiME (舞-HiME) was named for main character Mai, but being a homophone for My was intentional and that was carried into My-Otome (which was at one point going to be called [https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/images/misc/News.2005-06-09.MaiMaid.jpg](舞☆MAiD) - My/Mai Star Maid, a play on “Meister Maid”)

Answer (score 4):

Okay... I am not familiar with this anime, and I don't fully understand the information I've pieced together from TVTropes and snippets of Youtube vids.

But I believe this to be *My-Otome* ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My-Otome), [TVTropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Anime/MyOtome)). In particular, I think this is its prequel series, [My-Otome 0~S.ifr~](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Anime/MyOtome0Sifr).

> I remember the girls going to an all-girl school together.

The main characters all go to the "Garderobe Academy". I THINK it's an all-girls boarding school intended to train the Otomes.

> Each girl gets an earring to "seal" the pact with whoever to use the power.

They certainly all use earrings to morph into their superhero forms. Here's a couple of Youtube screenshots of the earrings:

[image: Red earring, showing text that says "ROBE.PEARL MATERIALISE START"]
[image: The earring glowing as the power is used]

> eyes say something like "blu rose lvl restriction lifted".

Here's a screenshot from when one character used the blue earring:

[image: Blue earring, showing text that says "END RESTRICTION"]

That "end restriction" may not be part of the usual morph sequence for that earring. But the below text is:

[image: Blue earring, showing text that says "ROBE: BLUE SKY SAPPHIRE MATERIALISE]

> Each color (blue, black, red, green) is different with different powers.
> ...
> The black power is "evil" and I remember the girl getting it by bonding(?) with some young boy who is a typical a**hole.

This is supposedly the "Ultimate Black Diamond" that Nina uses in the main series, although despite the text it doesn't look black:

[image: Red earring, showing text that says "ROBE: Ultimate Black Diamond MATERIALISE standing by"]

As for it being evil, [the series wiki](https://mai.fandom.com/wiki/Nina_W%C3%A1ng) states:

> Nina carries the Ultimate Black Diamond ... and forms a contract with Nagi. It's later revealed that the Ultimate Black Diamond is the corrupted Pure White Diamond.

And TVTropes states:

> Her Ultimate Black Diamond, according to the character guide, is representative of her "extreme and mostly selfish" love for Sergay, which is antithetical to the Otomes' selfless devotion to their masters.

I think she gets an emerald to use instead in the sequel series, My-Otome Zwei.

As far as I can tell, [this person, Nagi Dài Artai](https://mai.fandom.com/wiki/Nagi_D%C3%A0i_Artai), is the "boy who is a typical a**hole".

> When it's time to fight they "ask" something/-one for permission(?) to activate their power.

TVTropes states that *"the Otomes' powers can only be activated by the vocal command of their 'masters'."*

That said, there *may* be at least one situation where an Otome activated her power without permission. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=emJmqoSeAjo) is from the third episode of the prequel series. In it, Lena/Rena has entered an even more powerful version of her morphed form, known as "Super Meister". In this form, the glowing bands that suppress the Otome's power and keep them bound to their "masters" have shattered. We see the broken remains of those bands falling away from her costume in this screenshot:

[image: Bright bands falling away from the costume]

(This is also a different version of her usual superhero costume. It's not just the bands vanishing.)

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KX913sIuXV0) gives us more context. I think she enters the unrestricted morph form to protect her daughter. Here is a close-up screenshot of the text on her earring as she morphs:

[image: Pale blue earring, showing text that says "WARNING: unathorized access"]